# Why is "Billing" location type marked "reserved"?

Tags: configuration, location-type

What I was trying to do was disable the Billing location type, but I see in the database it's marked is_reserved=1, so it won't let you do it through the UI. But on a fresh install it's not even the default location type, so why is it marked reserved?

I was able to set is_reserved=0 in the database and then disable it, but wondering if this is going to break anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think billing location type is used incase of Online membership purchase or registering a event or making donation inshort on forms where payment processor is involved(Billing block). Disabling this might cause issue/problem during submit of such form.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Ok thanks. I suppose what I could also do is leave the "name" field in the database as "Billing" but change the label, and then disable other location types instead.

Comment: Following your answer I did find in the user guide where it says "Note that that Billing location is assigned to Billing Addresses entered when constituents contribute or pay for event and membership fees online." A (very) quick search thru the code doesn't see any obvious problems with my above comment, so going to go with that.

Comment: I had trouble with that in the past @Demerit but I think it was fixed in later versions.